# How to set an image as a background of a graph?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to set a background image in graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10054202/how-to-set-a-background-image-in-graph)

I am implementing one application related to graphs.

I am using Achartengine.jar is used to implement the graph.

My problem is when i am setting background color to graph it is applied fine.

I want set an image as a background of graph.

But it is not set properly.

When i set an image as background, the image is displayed within x,y-axis.

Not displayed on the margins of X,Y-axis.

my code is as follows

[How to set a background image in graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10054202/how-to-set-a-background-image-in-graph)

if any one know how to rectify this problem please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You asked same question which you asked two days ago, why so?

Answer (score 0):

I have applied  background to my graph like this

```
renderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
renderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
renderer.setMarginsColor(Color.WHITE);
```

Comment: my issue is not set background color.I want to set background image like background color.

Comment: renderer.setBackgroundColor(R.drawable.image); try like this